How to declare local types in typescript?
I'd like to declare some kind of local type inside a class, just like this :
class A {
    type LocalType = ...

    // Class body
}

to make it clear that LocalType belongs to class A and is to be used only in relation with it, with A.LocalType. I know there's... well, Typescript's  namespace's, but I find this solution somewhat messy : it makes the intention less clear, and I don't like the idea of a namespace and a class having the same name :
class A {
    // Class body
}

namespace A {
    export type LocalType = ...
}

Is there another way to achieve (maybe even roughly) the same behavior ?
Thanks !

Put the class and helper types into separate module. That's it, no namespaces, obvious relation, clear intention.

Why don’t you like the idea of namespaces and classes sharing a name? That sort of thing is common in TypeScript. Using a namespace to hold your types is how I’d recommend doing what you’re describing. It may be “messy” but it’s the supported approach. As for declaring a local type, there are feature requests for that but it’s not part of TS. How should we proceed here?
